# How to save array of structres in .mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab

How to save array of structures in `.mat` file in Matlab? Is it possible?

```
p(1).x=0;
p(1).y=0;

p(2).x=1;
p(2).y=1;

save('matfilename','-struct','p');
% ??? Error using ==> save
% The argument to -STRUCT must be the name of a scalar structure variable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `save` without the `-struct` parameter:

```
>> p(1).x = 0;
>> p(1).y = 0;
>> p(2).x = 1;
>> p(2).y = 1;
>> save('myvars.mat', 'p');
>> clear p;
>> load('myvars.mat');
>> p(1)

ans = 

    x: 0
    y: 0

>> p(2)

ans = 

    x: 1
    y: 1
```

If you want want to store `x` and `y` as separate arrays (as `-store` would if `p` was a scalar struct) then you'll need to do it yourself (you can use the `fieldnames` function to collect the names of all fields in a struct).